I need help because my replit isnt working and Im getting frustrated
https://replit.com/@barkeraamari1/34wong-2 I keep trying to run my replit and everytime it says disconnected and to reload and stuff like that. Even when I click the green it doesnt even load it and it just kicks me out. I was going to buy premium but I dont want to anymore since i dont even know if when I get that Ill be able to code my replit.
https://replit.com/@barkeraamari1/34wong-2 My replit will always for some reason say disconnected every time I click the run button can you please help.
I tried clear my cookies got a new router, reset my computer, used my phone, nothing works
